# VBA: The use of GoTo for non errors

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, switch-statement, goto

Just a quick question today, I am new to VBA and I am currently writing some code. In the code I use `GoTo` not for errors but just to write two different parts of functionality. For example the below:

```
Sub run_FetchTradeFilter()

    Dim EntrySelection As Range
    Set EntrySelection = Selection

    [EntireTradeQuery].Calculate
    If [CustomQuery] = True Then GoTo CaseCustomQuery Else GoTo CaseCustomList

CustomQuery:
    'fill
    'with
    'ccde A

CustomList:
    'fill
    'with
    'ccde B

    EntrySelection.Select

End Sub
```

My question is, should I be using `GoTo` if its not for an error. Or should I be using an if statement or should I be using a `SwitchCase`?

Comment: `GoTo` creates spaghetti code. It should be avoided.

Comment: I think the clue might be in your question *write to two different parts of functionality*. Have a read of `Functions` for VBA as this is probably the way you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

Great, thanks to both for the clarification! Bets to avoid `GoTo`. Therefore I will write 2 separate functions and call them in the `If` statement